# Android Binding Adapter attribute not found

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding

I am using a binding adapter to have mutable text in one of my views.  I believe I have it implemented correctly (and it's working in other places), but for the case of mutableText, it's getting the error `AAPT: error: attribute mutableText not found`

I've looked through some other answers on here, but none of them have been able to solve the issue.

Here is my layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.example.nhlstats.ui.game.GameViewModel" />
    </data>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/awayTeam"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/awayTeamLogo"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                tools:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/awayTeamName"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                app:mutableText="@{viewModel.getAwayTeamName()}"
                tools:text="CHI Blackhawks"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/awayScore"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                app:mutableText="@{viewModel.getAwayTeamScore().toString()}"
                tools:text="0"/>
            <TextView

                android:id="@+id/gameTime"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                app:mutableText="@{viewModel.getTimeRemaining()"
                tools:text="14:26 3rd"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/homeTeam"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/homeTeamLogo"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                tools:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/homeTeamName"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                app:mutableText="@{viewModel.getHomeTeamName()}"
                tools:text="CAR Hurricanes"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/homeScore"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                app:mutableText="@{viewModel.getHomeTeamScore().toString()}"
                tools:text="4"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

and my BindingAdpater function:

```
@BindingAdapter("mutableText")
fun setMutableText(view: TextView, text: MutableLiveData<String>?) {
    val parentActivity:AppCompatActivity? = view.getParentActivity()
    if (parentActivity != null && text != null) {
        text.observe(parentActivity, Observer { value ->
            view.text = value?:""
        })
    }
}
```

GameViewModel:

```
class GameViewModel:BaseViewModel() {
    private val awayTeamName = MutableLiveData<String>()
    private val homeTeamName = MutableLiveData<String>()
    private val awayTeamScore = MutableLiveData<Int>()
    private val homeTeamScore = MutableLiveData<Int>()
    private val timeRemaining = MutableLiveData<String>()

    fun bind(response: Game) {
        awayTeamName.value = response.gameData.teams.get(0).name
        homeTeamName.value = response.gameData.teams.get(1).name
        awayTeamScore.value = response.liveData.linescore.teams.get(1).goals
        homeTeamScore.value = response.liveData.linescore.teams.get(0).goals
        timeRemaining.value = response.liveData.linescore.currentPeriodOrdinal + " " + response.liveData.linescore.currentPeriodTimeRemaining
    }

    fun getAwayTeamName(): MutableLiveData<String> {
        return awayTeamName
    }

    fun getHomeTeamName(): MutableLiveData<String> {
        return homeTeamName
    }

    fun getAwayTeamScore(): MutableLiveData<Int> {
        return awayTeamScore
    }

    fun getHomeTeamScore(): MutableLiveData<Int> {
        return homeTeamScore
    }

    fun getTimeRemaining(): MutableLiveData<String> {
        return timeRemaining
    }
}
```

MainActivity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private lateinit var viewModel: GameListViewModel
    private var errorSnackbar: Snackbar? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)
        binding.gameList.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)

        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(GameListViewModel::class.java)
        viewModel.errorMessage.observe(this, Observer { errorMessage ->
            if (errorMessage != null)
                showError(errorMessage)
            else
                hideError()
        })
        binding.viewModel = viewModel
    }

    private fun showError(@StringRes errorMessage:Int) {
        errorSnackbar = Snackbar.make(binding.root, errorMessage, Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
        errorSnackbar?.setAction(R.string.retry, viewModel.errorClickListener)
        errorSnackbar?.show()
    }

    private fun hideError() {
        errorSnackbar?.dismiss()
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. Why do you need a custom binding adapter for TextView + MutableLiveData? You can directly assign the LiveData to your TextView in XML like `android:text="@{viewModel.getHomeTeamScore}"` and it should work
2. Have you put `setMutableText` in `companion object` with `@JvmStatic`

Comment: 1. I did that so that it supports data that could change when an API is called again, will your suggestion also support that? 2. I haven't, but I didn't do that with my other bindings in the bindingadapter and those are working fine

Comment: Yes, whenever your data changes, for example you received a new data through API, just call the `setValue()` of `MutableLiveData` again and it'll automatically reflect. Can you please add your `GameViewModel` code as well?

Comment: I added the GameViewModel code above.  I checked in ActivityMainBindingImpl (a generated class) and only setMutableVisibility and setAdapter are being used (generated), setMutableText isn't, and shows that the setMutableText function isn't being used anywhere

Answer (score 0):

Your binding adapter receives a nullable value, while the viewModel returns a non-null value. Change the text parameter to be non-null, just like the function in the viewModel returns it.

You can also do shorter encapsulation, for example:

```
private val _data = MutableLiveData<String>()
val data: LiveData<String>
  get() = _data
```

This way you don't have to write long and boring getters like in Java.

Answer (score 0):

As per your `GameViewModel`, I don't think you need any custom binding adapter.

Please check the edited code.

**GameViewModel**

```
class GameViewModel:BaseViewModel() {
    // Make the variables public and access directly instead of exposing them via get() method.
    val awayTeamName = MutableLiveData<String>()
    val homeTeamName = MutableLiveData<String>()
    val awayTeamScore = MutableLiveData<String>() // Change to String
    val homeTeamScore = MutableLiveData<String>() // Change to String
    val timeRemaining = MutableLiveData<String>()

    fun bind(response: Game) {
        awayTeamName.value = response.gameData.teams.get(0).name
        homeTeamName.value = response.gameData.teams.get(1).name
        awayTeamScore.value = response.liveData.linescore.teams.get(1).goals.toString() // Convert to String from here only instead of writing it in XML!
        homeTeamScore.value = response.liveData.linescore.teams.get(0).goals.toString()
        timeRemaining.value = response.liveData.linescore.currentPeriodOrdinal + " " + response.liveData.linescore.currentPeriodTimeRemaining
    }
}
```

**Your layout file**(Notice I accessed the variables directly and removed the toString() as we are now only exposing `MutableLiveData` with `String` and yes, we are not using your custom binding adapter.

```
<data>
    <variable
        name="viewModel"
        type="com.example.nhlstats.ui.game.GameViewModel" />
</data>
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/awayTeam"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/awayTeamLogo"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            tools:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/awayTeamName"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="@{viewModel.awayTeamName}"
            tools:text="CHI Blackhawks"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/awayScore"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="@{viewModel.awayTeamScore}"
            tools:text="0"/>
        <TextView

            android:id="@+id/gameTime"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="@{viewModel.timeRemaining}"
            tools:text="14:26 3rd"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/homeTeam"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/homeTeamLogo"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            tools:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/homeTeamName"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="@{viewModel.homeTeamName}"
            tools:text="CAR Hurricanes"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/homeScore"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:text="@{viewModel.homeTeamScore}"
            tools:text="4"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I haven't tested this so let me know how this goes for you.

Comment: I'm having the issue now where I'm properly receiving data, but it isn't showing in the UI, except when I debug through it slowly, then it shows.  I suspect this is because something isn't being updated, which is why I was using MutableLiveData, so it would do that automatically through an observer.  Any ideas why the mutableText wasn't being generated but the other two were?

Comment: Have you bind your ViewModel with your activity/fragment and have you set lifecycle owner?

Comment: I have bound it, not sure about lifecycle owner.  I added MainActivity code to my original question, that's where it's bound

Comment: please add `binding.lifecycleOwner = this` below `binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(...)` and please make sure when you receive `Game` response and you call `viewModel.bind()` from your activity, it's being called on UI Thread and not from any background thread.

Comment: The only place I'm calling viewModel.bind() is in the recyclerview's ViewHolder bind() method, called from onBindViewHolder

Comment: Oh yes, you have two `ViewModel`s. One is for activity and one is for the recyclerview item if I understood correct. Then the problem lies in your adapter and not activity as it looks fine to me.

Comment: https://github.com/jollygreenegiant/NHLStats is the github repo if you want to pull it and give it a shot

Comment: Buddy, the problem is in `onRetrieveScheduleSuccess` method of `GameListViewModel`. You are looping through `ScheduleGame` and for each game you are calling an API to get some extra data. That API call is async and it'll come after some time, but without waiting for all the data to come, you are directly calling `gameListAdapter.updateGameList(gameList)`. When that line is executed, you don't have any item in your gameList! So please call it only after you have all the data from your API call.

Comment: Wow, that should have been obvious.  Thanks for all your help