# : attribute mutableText (aka yodgorbekkomilov.edgar.footballapp:mutableText) not found.?

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, data-binding, two-way-binding

I am developing a football statics app  I have used binding adapter but I am getting the following error in my `football_item.xml` file

```
C:\Users\Edgar\Desktop\FootballApp\app\src\main\res\layout\football_item.xml:17: AAPT: error: attribute mutableText (aka yodgorbekkomilov.edgar.footballapp:mutableText) not found.
```

¨

Below is my xml file  where I am getting error

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<data>
    <variable
        name="viewModel"
        type="yodgorbekkomilov.edgar.footballapp.ui.FootballViewModel" />
</data>


<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
   >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:mutableText="@{viewModel.clubName"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:mutableText="@{viewModel.countryName"/>





    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:mutableText="@{viewModel.clubValue"/>

    <ImageView
        app:imageUrl="@{viewModel.image}"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:id="@+id/clubImage"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:mutableText="@{viewModel.europeanTitle}"/>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Below is my `bindingAdapter` class where I have used `bindingadapter`

```
@BindingAdapter("mutableText")
fun setMutableText(view: TextView, text: MutableLiveData<String>?) {
    val parentActivity:AppCompatActivity? = view.getParentActivity()
    if(parentActivity != null && text != null) {
        text.observe(parentActivity, Observer { value -> view.text = value?:""})
    }
```

Below is my `FootballListViewModel.kt`

```
class FootballViewModel: BaseViewModel() {
    private val clubName = MutableLiveData<String>()

    private val countryName = MutableLiveData<String>()
    private val clubValue = MutableLiveData<Int>()
    private val clubImage = MutableLiveData<String>()
    private val europeanTitle = MutableLiveData<Int>()

    fun bind(football: FootballResponse){
        clubName.value= football[0].name
        countryName.value = football[1].country
        clubValue.value = football[2].value
        clubImage.value = football[3].image
        europeanTitle.value = football[4].europeanTitles

    }

    fun getClubName():MutableLiveData<String>{
        return clubName
    }

    fun getCountryName():MutableLiveData<String>{
        return countryName
    }

    fun getClubValue():MutableLiveData<Int>{
        return clubValue
    }

    fun getImage():MutableLiveData<String> {
 return clubImage

    }


    fun getEuropeanTitle():MutableLiveData<Int> {
        return europeanTitle

    }
}
```

Below is `FootballResponseItem.kt`

```
data class FootballResponseItem(
    @SerializedName("country")
    val country: String,
    @SerializedName("european_titles")
    val europeanTitles: Int,
    @SerializedName("image")
    val image: String,
    @SerializedName("name")
    val name: String,
    @SerializedName("value")
    val value: Int
)
```

Below is `FootballResponse.kt`

```
class FootballResponse : ArrayList<FootballResponseItem>()
```

What I have tried to solve the problem:

1. Invalidate cache restart
2. Followed this [Android Binding Adapter attribute not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58576992/android-binding-adapter-attribute-not-found) link. Tried suggested answer, but it did not solve my problem

What I have to do in order to avoid the problem? Any help and suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It looks like you are missing some curly brackets in some of your mutableText statements. `app:mutableText="@{viewModel.clubValue"`. Is this a formatting error or actually in your code? If the latter, you should probably correct that.

Comment: @Cheesebaron I already fixed problem but now I am getting another problem maybe you can check that post

Comment: Can you please go ahead and put the answer to your post here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hava changed  my xml file followingly then it started working

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<data>
    <variable
        name="viewModel"
        type="yodgorbekkomilov.edgar.footballapp.ui.FootballViewModel" />
</data>


<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
   >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:mutableText="@{viewModel.clubName}"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:mutableText="@{viewModel.countryName}"/>





    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:mutableText="@{viewModel.clubValue}"/>

    <ImageView
        app:imageUrl="@{viewModel.image}"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:mutableText="@{viewModel.europeanTitle}"/>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```